# Error al pasar como parámetro un objeto hacia otra clase "error: no matching function for call to 'Card::Card()' Node::Node(Card card, Node *next) {"

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, nodos

La idea del codigo es una lista enlazada "LinkedList" la cual se encarga de almacenar valores de tipo Carta "Card"

***Clase Card:***
Es donde define el valor que se guardara la lista enlazada tiene un numero y un tipo como las cartas de jugar poker.

```
class Card {
private:
    string number;
    CardType type;
public:
    Card(string number, CardType type);
};

Card::Card(string number, CardType type) {
  this->number = number;
  this->type = type;
}
```

***Clase Node:***  se define el nodo que funciona de la misma manera que en cualquier linkedlist para formar la misma con un puntero "next" que apunta a un próximo nodo y el valor que en este caso es "Card"

```
class Node {
  public:
    Card card;
    Node* next;
    Node(Card card, Node* next = nullptr);
    Node(Node* next = nullptr);
};

Node::Node(Card card, Node *next) {
  this->card = card;
  this->next = next;
}

Node::Node(Node *next) {
  this->next = next;
}
```

***Linked List:*** Es la estructura que contiene la lógica de inserción y eliminación de nodos
Tiene un puntero a la cabeza y la cola de dicha lista.

```
class LinkedList : public List {
  private:
    Card card;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    Node* current;
    int size;
  public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void append(Card card);
}

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
  head = new Node();
  tail = new Node();
  current = new Node();
  size = 0;
}

void LinkedList::append(Card a) {
  cout << a.getNumber() << endl;
  tail->next = new Node(a);
  tail = tail->next;
  size ++;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
int main() {
  LinkedList a;
  a.append(Card("A", CardType::HEARTS));
  a.append(Card("J", CardType::HEARTS));
  a.append(Card("Q", CardType::HEARTS));
  a.append(Card("K", CardType::HEARTS));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es en la linea( tail->next = new Node(a);), estas pasando una Card como parámetro cuando no tenes un constructor para eso, espera un Node o una Card y un Node.